# Ember conditional rendering is adding a weird element in DOM

Tags: dom, ember.js, ember-cli

Whenever a condition is not respected in my template I noticed this green thing in the DOM

[image]

Can this behavior be avoided ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just an empty html-comment-tag

```
<html>
    <!-- this is a comment -->
</html>
```

comments are not displayed in browsers. It's an implementation detail of ember, so cannot be avoided. There should no need to avoid it.